# How can I prove (without cardinal numbers) that $P(P(\mathbb{N}))$ is equipollent to $P(P(\mathbb{N})) \times P(P(\mathbb{N}))$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, set-theory, cardinals

I am stuck trying to prove that $P(P(\mathbb{N}))$ is equipollent to $P(P(\mathbb{N})) \times P(P(\mathbb{N}))$. I was thinking that it is enough to prove $P(\mathbb{R}) \sim P(\mathbb{R}) \times P(\mathbb{R})$, or even $2^{\mathbb{R}} \sim 2^{\mathbb{R}} \times 2^{\mathbb{R}}$ , but I still don't know how to finish this. It would be even better if you can prove that in general for any infinite set $X$ it's true that $X \times X \sim X$.

Comment: I suppose you mean ‘equipotent’?

Comment: @Bernard: Some authors (notably Hungerford) use "equipollent": two sets are equipollent if there is a bijection betweenthem.

Comment: The general fact $X\times X\sim X$ requires the axiom of choice, and avoiding cardinal numbers for proving it is quite unlikely.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: For me, ‘equipollent’  is used in geometry for pairs   of points (two pairs are equipollent if the define the same vector), whereas equipotence is related to power sets.

Comment: @HanulJeon Okay, but how about the original question? Can that be proved without cardinals? And also, does the fact $X \times X \sim X$ have a name or where can I look it up?

Comment: I have a counter-question: why should you avoid cardinals?

Comment: See [Tarski's theorem about choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_theorem_about_choice) on Wikipedia for $A\sim A\times A$.

Comment: Equipollent is the term I've seen in several books about equality of cardinals.

Comment: @HanulJeon the thing is we didn't cover cardinal numbers in this course (it is introduction to logic and set theorey, it's kind of an introduction to proofs in our universitry) and it is an old exam question.

Comment: @Bernard: I understand it is not universal nomenclature; that's why I said "some authors". I'm just pointing out that it is not *incorrect* nomenclature.

Comment: @DonAntonio: It is usually used because you don't have cardinals on hand. It's a notion that can be defined in the absence of the Axiom of Choice, and does not require the definition of cardinals ahead of time, as it is "just" a relation between sets. After you develop cardinals, you can prove that every set is equipollent to at most one cardinal (exactly one if you assume AC), and then define "the cardinal(ity) of a set" to be the (unique) cardinal it is equipollent to.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That's exactly how we defined it (although we did cover Axiom of Choice, but we defined the relation without it.

Comment: It's true that AC implies (and in fact is equivalent to) the statement that for all $X,$ $|X\times X| = |X|,$ but it's worth noting that much less choice is required to prove that for all $X,$ $|P(P(X))\times P(P(X))| =|P(P(X))|$ and no choice at all is required to prove either statement for the specific case $X=\mathbb N.$

Comment: Looking at these answers I'm starting to think that there's no simple way to show it even for the specific case $P(P(\mathbb{N}))$. I have absolutely no idea how I would come up with anything like these answers during the exam :(

Comment: @Matthew It helps to understand it it pieces. The calculation is $$2^{2^X} \times 2^{2^X} = 2^{2^X + 2^X} = 2^{2\times 2^X}= 2^{2^{X+1}}.$$ First understand the bijection that shows $2^A\times 2^B = 2^{A+B}$, then the one that shows $A + A = 2A,$ then the one that shows $2 \times 2^A = 2^{A+1}.$ Then you're just left with needing to show $\mathbb N = \mathbb N + 1,$ which is easy. I know you said no cardinal arithmetic, but it's really useful.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen thank you for this. Can you just tell me what $\mathbb{N} +1$ actually means?

Comment: @Matthew The cardinality of the disjoint union of $\mathbb N$ and a one-element set. (Probably should write it $|\mathbb N| + 1$, but I'm being sloppy with notation in general here.) In general $|A|+|B|$ means the cardinality of the disjoint union of $A$ and $B,$ and $1$ just means the cardinality of any one-element set.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thank you! And can you recommend me where I can find a good quick overview of this method (short because there isn't much time until the exam)? Because I don't understand why we can add the exponents just like in normal exponentiation and what this addition even means - for example in $2^X + 2^X$. Thanks!

Comment: @Matthew Sorry, I don't know of any good reference off the top of my head. I edited my previous comment while you were writing yours to clarify that addition means the cardinality of the disjoint union. You can see an explanation for why we can add the exponents in the first paragraph of Hanul Jeon's answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can see that for any sets $A$ and $B$, there is a bijection from $\mathcal{P}(A)\times \mathcal{P}(B)$ to $\mathcal{P}(A\sqcup B)$, where $A\sqcup B:=\{0\}\times A\cup \{1\}\times B$ is the disjoint union of $A$ and $B$: Just consider the map that sends $(X,Y)$ to $\{0\}\times X\cup \{1\}\times Y$.

(Note: Constructing the bijection does not require any knowledge about cardinals, but is directly related to showing equalities on cardinal arithmetic.)

Hence it suffices to construct a bijection between $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\sqcup \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. Here is a way to constructing it: for each $(i,X)$, consider $f(i,X)=\{0\mid i=1\}\cup \{n+1\mid n\in X\}$.

Comment: You could further factor the last step into: in general, there is a bijection between $\mathcal{P}(A) \sqcup \mathcal{P}(A)$ and $\mathcal{P}(A \sqcup \{ 0 \} )$, so you reduce to finding a bijection between $\mathbb{N} \sqcup \{ 0 \}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ (which is just the one from the Hilbert hotel "paradox").

Answer (score 2):

The statement that $|X|=|X\times X|$ is equivalent to the axiom of choice. You can prove it as follows. Let: $$\mathcal{H}:=\{f:B \longrightarrow B\times B : B\subset X \text{ and } f \text{ is a bijection}\}$$ with the relation order given by $g<h \Longleftrightarrow \operatorname{Dom}g\subset\operatorname{Dom} h \text{ and } h|_{\operatorname{Dom} g}=g$. It's easy to proof that for every chain $\mathcal{C}\subset\mathcal{H}$, the function defined as $f_\mathcal{C}(c):=f(c)$ if $c\in S\subset\mathcal{C}$ is well defined, is a element of $\mathcal{H}$ and is an upper bound for $\mathcal{C}$.

Hence there is a maximal $f_0\in\mathcal{H}$ (Zorn's Lemma). It can be proved (it's not an trivial proof, but I can write it down here if you want), that $\operatorname{Dom} f_0=X$, so $f_0$ is a bijection between $X$ and $X\times X$.

Let $A_0:=\operatorname{Dom} f_0$ and lets prove that there is a bijective map between $A_0$ and $X$.

For this purpose, assume that there exists a surjective aplication $g:X\setminus A_0\longrightarrow A_0$. Then, you can easily prove using axiom of choice that there exists $S\subset X\setminus A_0$ such that $\phi:=g|_{S}$ is bijective. Now note that:
$$(A_0\cup S)\times(A_0\cup S)=(A_0\times A_0)\cup(A_0\times S)\cup(S\times A_0)\cup(S\times S)$$
And also note that the function $\theta:=\phi\circ f_0\circ(\phi^{-1},\phi^{-1})$ is a bijection between $S$ and $S\times S$.

There exists a bijective map $j:S\longrightarrow(A_0\times S)\cup(S\times A_0)\cup(S\times S)$ (the existence of this map is given by the fact that $|S|=|S\times S|=|(A_0\times S)\cup(S\times A_0)\cup(S\times S)|$, because the union of disjoint sets of same cardinality has the same cardinality as any of the sets or without using cardinals at all, there is a bijection between $T$ and $T\cup P$ whenever there exists one between $T$ and $P$; again, if you want a proof of this I can write it down). Then, the map defined as:
\begin{align*}
    h_0:A_0\cup S &\longrightarrow(A_0\cup S)\times(A_0\cup S) \\
    x &\longmapsto h_0(x):=\begin{cases}f_0(x) &\text{ if } x\in A_0 \\
    j(x) &\text{ if } x\in S\setminus A_0\end{cases}
\end{align*}
is a bijection, and $h_0|_{A_0}=f_0$. Hence $f_0<h_0$, which is a contradiction. Then there doesn't exists a surjective map $g:X\setminus A_0\longrightarrow A_0$, which implies that there actually is a bijection $k:X\longrightarrow A_0$ (this is also a consecuence of the cardinality of union of disjoint sets). Finally, the map: $$k\circ f_0 \circ (k^{-1},k^{-1}): X\longrightarrow X\times X$$ is bijective, which concludes the proof.

Comment: Yes, I would love it if you can write it down!

Comment: So the question is: can choice be avoided in the special case stated in the OP?  Yes, you can.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, I've seen that now, but the question that still remains: is there a simple way to do so? I would love to see the proof of the general theorem, because than I would be able to apply it to many different cases if I happen to come accross one during the exam.

Comment: I've edited the post. The proof relies on the fact that if $|B|\leq|A|$ then $|A\cup B|=|A|$, which has a similar proof with the axiom of choice. The proof doesn't actually require any cardinal arithmetic because in order to define cardinal arithmetic you first need to prove it's well defined (which is proved with this two propositions). Anyways, the proof actually gets more visual, and easier if you allow to use cardinal notation, which I tried to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need the axiom of choice for this specific case of $|X|=|X\times X|$.

Let $f:\Bbb N\to 2\Bbb N:n\mapsto 2n$ and $g:\Bbb N\to 2\Bbb N+1:n\mapsto 2n+1$. Define

$$\begin{align*}
\varphi&:\wp(\wp(\Bbb N))\times\wp(\wp(\Bbb N))\to\wp(\wp(\Bbb N))\\
&:\langle\mathscr{A},\mathscr{B}\rangle\mapsto\{f[A]\cup g[B]:\langle A,B\rangle\in\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B}\}\,.
\end{align*}$$

The map $\varphi$ actually recoverably encodes each member of $\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B}$ as a subset of $\Bbb N$.

Suppose that $\mathscr{C}\in\operatorname{ran}\varphi$. For each $C\in\mathscr{C}$ let

$$A_C=\left\{\frac{n}2:n\in C\cap 2\Bbb N\right\}$$

and

$$B_C=\left\{\frac{n-1}2:n\in C\cap(2\Bbb N+1)\right\}\,;$$

then $C=f[A_C]\cup g[B_C]$. Let $\mathscr{A}=\{A_C:C\in\mathscr{C}\}$ and $\mathscr{B}=\{B_C:C\in\mathscr{C}\}$; then $\mathscr{C}=\varphi(\langle\mathscr{A},\mathscr{B}\rangle)$. Thus, $\varphi$ is an injection. Since there is an obvious injection in the other direction, the result follows from the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem.

In the original version of this answer I thought that I had avoided having to use the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem and incorrectly said that $\varphi$ was a bijection, but of course it is not: the range of $\varphi$ is the family of $\mathscr{C}\in\wp(\wp(\Bbb N))$ such that if $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$ are defined as in the previous paragraph, then $\mathscr{C}=\{f[A]\cup g[B]:\langle A,B\rangle\in\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B}\}$, so that $\mathscr{C}$ encodes all of $\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B}$, not just an arbitrary set $\mathscr{D}\subseteq\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B}$ big enough so that $\pi_0[\mathscr{D}]=\mathscr{A}$ and $\pi_1[\mathscr{D}]=\mathscr{B}$.

Comment: Your $\varphi$ can't possibly be a bijection. Any member of its image will be a collection of subsets of $\mathbb N$ each of which contains either all even or all odd numbers. Any collection which includes a set containing both odd and even numbers will be missed. ($\varphi(\langle\mathscr{A},\mathscr{B}\rangle$ has elements $f[A_C]$ and $g[B_C]$ but not $f[A_C]\cup g[B_C]$.) However it is an injection, which is all you need.  An injection in the other direction is straightforward so the Schroeder-Bernstein lemma gives a bijection.

Comment: @DavidHartley: It should have been clear from the calculation of the inverse that there was a typo in the definition of $\varphi$: the union was in the wrong place. The map still isn’t a bijection, since it encodes the entire Cartesian product of the two input families; *that* was a genuine oversight on my part.